# Fast way of calculating hamming distance in haskell

Tags: haskell

What is a fast way of calculating hamming distance in haskell, given two strings.

For example, sample input:

`GGGCCGTTGGT` and `GGACCGTTGAC`

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: What is the type of the input? A string? A list of `NucleoBasis`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can calculate the Hamming distance for two lists (with equal length) with the same type, given the type is an instance of the `Eq` type class, with:

```
hammingDistance :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Int
hammingDistance = (sum .) . zipWith ((fromEnum .) . (/=))
```

or an alternative:

```
hammingDistance :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Int
hammingDistance la lb = length (filter id (zipWith (/=) la lb))
```

For example:

```
Prelude> hammingDistance "GGGCCGTTGGT" "GGACCGTTGAC"
3
```

Both functions work more or less in a similar way: we enumerate over the two lists concurrently, and for the two elements we check if the two are not equal. We then count the number of elements that are not equal.

## Making it more *safe*

Since it is possible to call the above function with two lists with a different length, it might be better - like @JonPurdy suggests - to change the function, and add some checks. We can for example implement a function with signature:

```
hammingDistance :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe Int
```

Here we return `Nothing` in case the two lists have a different length, or `Just x` (with `x` the hamming distance of the two lists). We can for example write this with recursion:

```
hammingDistance :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Int
hammingDistance (x:xs) (y:ys) | x /= y = fmap (+1) tl
                              | otherwise = tl
    where tl = hammingDistance xs ys
hammingDistance [] [] = Just 0
hammingDistance _ _ = Nothing
```

Comment: What about using a recursive function? Such as
`hD' :: Eq a => Int -> [a] -> [a] -> Int`
`hD' n [] _ = n`
`hD' n _ [] = n`
`hD' n (x:xs) (y:ys) | x == y = hd' (n+1) xs ys`
                             `| otherwise = hd' n xs ys`

Comment: @DominikSchrempf: you probably should replace `x == y` for `x /= y`, but this will indeed do the trick :)

Comment: Another idiom I’ve seen for counting things that match a condition, instead of `length`+`filter`, is `sum [1 | (a, b) <- zip la lb, a /= b]`, which is a pretty nice literal transcription of the problem: add 1 to the distance for each pair of characters in the two strings that differ at the same position. Also worth noting that Hamming distance is only defined for strings of equal length, so including a length check and calling `error` or returning `Maybe` would be better—the advantage of the direct recursive solution is that this check can be included in the same traversal as the calculation.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem :), thanks! Because it interested me, I checked runtimes of the three possibilities (I did not use the Maybe type so that the comparison is more fair) on a ~1500 bp sequence with Criterion. The function using `filter` is slightly slower, than the other two, which have about the same speed. If the question is reopened, I can post my results (or I can edit your answer).